# OCaml : need help for List.map function

Tags: string, list, ocaml

I need to create a function that basically works like this :

```
insert_char("string" 'x') outputs "sxtxrxixnxg".
```

So here is my reasoning :

Create a list with every single character in the string :

```
let inserer_car(s, c) = 
    let l = ref [] in
for i = 0 to string.length(s) - 1 do
   l := s.[i] :: !l
done;
```

Then, I want to use `List.map` to turn it into a list like `['s', 'x', 't', 'x' etc.]`.

However, I don't really know how to create my function to use with map. Any help would be appreciated!

I'm a beginner in programming and especially in *ocaml!* so feel free to assume I'm absolutely ignorant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map function creates a copy of a structure with different contents. For lists, this means that `List.map f list` has the same length as `list`. So, this won't work for you. Your problem requires the full power of a fold.

(You could also solve the problem imperatively, but in my opinion the reason to study OCaml is to learn about functional programming.)

Let's say you're going to use `List.fold_left`. Then the call looks like this:

```
let result = List.fold_left myfun [] !l
```

Your function `myfun` has the type `char list -> char -> char list`. In essence, its first parameter is the result you've built so far and its second parameter is the next character of the input list `!l`. The result should be what you get when you add the new character to the list you have so far.

At the end you'll need to convert a list of characters back to a string.

Comment: Thanks, could you please give me a basic example of a proper myfun function? I'm not quite sure about the syntax.

Comment: A function that takes two parameters: `let f a b = b :: a`.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using Core, you could write it like this:

```
open Core.Std

let insert_char s c =
  String.to_list s
  |> (fun l -> List.intersperse l c)
  |> String.of_char_list
```

Or, equivalently:

```
let insert_char s c =
  let chars = String.to_list s in
  let interspersed_chars = List.intersperse chars c in
  String.of_char_list interspersed_chars
```

This is just straightforward use of existing librariies.  If you want the implementation of `List.intersperse`, you can find it [here](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/blob/master/lib/core_list.ml#L1075).  It's quite simple.